# Execute or Testfor a named dropped Item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a contraption set up where if I drop a player head named *Camera1* (it looked very much like a camera) a clock will find it and replace it with an armor stand that is also wearing the head.

It will then destroy the dropped head, give me *Camera2*, an item that I'll use to look from the first camera's perspective, and a kill switch to destroy all placed camera.

*Yeah. Ambitious.* Anyways, I have most of the details smoothed out but one:

How do I test for the item *Camera1*, in the air? I tried using `/Execute`, and that can find an item, but I don't want every item I drop to be a camera, neither do I want anyone else on the server to have the same trouble either. Can I `/Testfor` it somehow? Also, if I'm in a room with a ceiling four blocks off the floor, will it be fast enough that I can throw the item at the corner of the ceiling and have the armorstand spawn before it hits the ground?

Comment: So basically, you want to do [this](https://youtu.be/qrha072pX60)?

Answer (score 3):

Use a partial NBT Test to find all items named Camera1 that is a head of a specific player.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add isCamera dummy
```

Clock (20 tps):

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] isCamera 1 {Item:{Damage:3, id:397, tag:{display:{Name:Bob}, Skull_Owner:<Skull Owner>}}}
/execute @e[score_isCamera_min=1] <x> <y> <z> <Command>
```

This will instantly find all Player Heads with the Owner of the `<Head Owner>` and the name of Camera1 immediately when dropped, or to be specific within 1 twentieth to 2 twentieth of a second, which will not give time for the item to fall.