# How to testfor a dropped item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know this question is like [Execute or Testfor a named dropped Item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223019/execute-or-testfor-a-named-dropped-item), but I couldn't fit the answer there to my needs. So, I'm working on a spear in my one-command creation. It is a stick renamed spear. So I want to be able to testfor when it is dropped, so it would be like "throwing" it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this command:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"spear"}}}}
```

Or, if you have more items named "spear" use this:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:minecraft:stick,tag:{display:{Name:"spear"}}}}
```

Now just hook this on a Redstone clock/Put it into a Repeat Command block and you're done!

---

If you have only 1 command following this, use tags and the `/execute` command:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add IsSpear {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:spear}}}}
```

And instead of the `/testfor` command use `/execute`:

```
/execute @e[type=Item,tag=IsSpear] ~ ~ ~ /yourcommand
```

Comment: thanks so much i looked all over the internet and couldn't find anything! +1

Comment: @hyperviper11 thanks for checking my post!

Answer (score 0):

there's such an easier way to do this.

```
/testfor @e[type=item,name=item.item.stick] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:spear}}}}
```

Put this in an always active repeating command block, then make it point to a conditional chain that's always active and facing away from the repeating, in a series that looks sort of like this:

```
|> >>
```

Then type your command in the chain command block.